# Subsetting in R returns different values using %in% vs. == operator

Tags: r, subset

I'm new to R, and learning several ways to subset data. I'm puzzle by the difference in the number of matches using the below in a Restaurant Data (RestData) set by zipcode.

```
> nrow(restData[restData$zipCode %in% c("21212","21213"),])
# [1] 59
> nrow(restData[restData$zipCode == c("21212","21213"),])
# [1] 26

>Warning message:
In restData$zipCode == c("21212", "21213") :
 longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

I'm using the below dataset in case you want to replicate

```
fileURL <- "https://data.baltimorecity.gov/api/views/k5ry-ef3g/rows.csv?accessType=DOWNLOAD"
download.file(fileURL, destfile = "./Rdata/restaurants.csv", method = "curl")
restData <- read.csv("./Rdata/restaurants.csv")
```

Comment: Have you done any searching??????????

Comment: You could also do some experimenting: `x = 1:5;
x %in% c(1,3);
x == c(1,3);
x == c(3,1);
x==1;
x==3;
x==1 | x==3; x[x %in% c(1,3)]; x[x == c(3,1)]`, etc.

Comment: I see what you mean, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not getting the same answers because both lines are not doing the same! The first one is the right one if you want to index the positions of `RestData` where the zip code is either `"21212"` or `"21213"`. See `?"%in%"` for more details.

In the second line, it's important to know R will "recycle" the elements of a shorter vector when needed for a binary operation. For example, `1:6 + 1:2` will recycle the second vector (of length two) to make it a vector of length 6, so you really do `1:6 + rep(1:2, length=6)`. In your case, you are doing

```
restData$zipCode == rep(c("21212", "21213"), length=nrow(restData))
```

an the comparison is done element by element. So, it's telling you when the odd positions are `"21212"` or the even positions are `"21213"`. The warning you're getting is important, because is telling you're comparing a vector of odd length with a vector of even length. In some cases the recycling can be useful, for example `restData$zipCode[c(TRUE, FALSE)]` will retrieve only the odd positions.